# groupby multiple columns and broadcast results back to each row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have posted this question before, but it keeps getting closed due to having similar questions asked, but those solutions have not helped me here.

I have a dataframe that needs to be grouped by 3 different columns. From the resultant groupings, I need to perform calculations and then apply the result to each row in a new column.

My data looks like this:

```
ID   Deal  Party  Commodity       startdate  enddate  fixedpricestrike  quantity  mtmvalue
---- ----- -----  ---------       ---------  -------  ----------------  --------  ---------
J1   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        10.00          10      100.00
J2   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        10.00          10      100.00
J3   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        5.00           10      50.00
J4   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        5.00           5       25.00
```

My objective is to group the data by [Deal, commodity, startdate] so that the resultant data looks like this:

```
ID   Deal  Party  Commodity       startdate  enddate  fixedpricestrike  quantity  mtmvalue
---- ----- -----  ---------       ---------  -------  ----------------  --------  ---------
J1   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        10.00          10      100.00
J2   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        10.00          10      100.00

ID   Deal  Party  Commodity       startdate  enddate  fixedpricestrike  quantity  mtmvalue
---- ----- -----  ---------       ---------  -------  ----------------  --------  ---------
J3   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        5.00           10      50.00
J4   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        5.00           5       25.00
```

From this, I need to use a formula to calculate a 'fprice' and add it to each row like this:

```
ID   Deal  Party  Commodity       startdate  enddate  fixedpricestrike  quantity  mtmvalue fprice
---- ----- -----  ---------       ---------  -------  ----------------  --------  --------- -----
J1   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        10.00          10      100.00    0
J2   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        10.00          10      100.00    0

ID   Deal  Party  Commodity       startdate  enddate  fixedpricestrike  quantity  mtmvalue fprice
---- ----- -----  ---------       ---------  -------  ----------------  --------  --------- -----
J3   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        5.00           10      50.00     1.25
J4   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        5.00           10      25.00     1.25
```

My issue lies in the next step, when I try to add the fprice back to the original dataframe
I have this line of code:

```
df['fprice'] = df.groupby(['StartDate', 'Commodity', 'Deal']).apply(lambda group: -(group['MTMValue'].sum() - (group['FixedPriceStrike'] * group['Quantity']).sum()) / group['Quantity'].sum()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

which returns this dataframe:

```
ID   Deal  Party  Commodity       startdate  enddate  fixedpricestrike  quantity  mtmvalue fprice
---- ----- -----  ---------       ---------  -------  ----------------  --------  --------- -----
J1   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        10.00          10      100.00    0
J2   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        10.00          10      100.00    1.25
J3   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        5.00           10      50.00     
J4   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        5.00           10      25.00
```

when the result should look like

```
ID   Deal  Party  Commodity       startdate  enddate  fixedpricestrike  quantity  mtmvalue fprice
---- ----- -----  ---------       ---------  -------  ----------------  --------  --------- -----
J1   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        10.00          10      100.00    0
J2   Sell   J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        10.00          10      100.00    0
J3   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        5.00           10      50.00     1.25
J4   Buy    J   (stock1, stock2)   01Jan23   01Feb23        5.00           10      25.00     1.25
```

I am also relatively new to using pandas, and I am unsure why my result is coming out this way. Any suggestions would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it in one step, you can first calculate the 'fprice' and then merge it back to the original DataFrame:

```py
# Calculate 'fprice' for each group
grouped = df.groupby(['startdate', 'Commodity', 'Deal']).apply(
    lambda group: -(group['mtmvalue'].sum() - (group['fixedpricestrike'] * group['quantity']).sum()) / group['quantity'].sum()
).reset_index(name='fprice')

# Merge 'fprice' back to the original DataFrame
df = pd.merge(df, grouped, on=['startdate', 'Commodity', 'Deal'], how='left')
```